# Can Hotel management done in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

My question is 
Can I use sharepoint 2013 to make a hotel management program ??
if there is a way could you please tell me where to begin ?

Comment: Much too wide a question I'm afraid. What kind of hotel, what kind of SP - online? - onprem? If onprem and you are asking here, I'm guessing that you don't have much budget and not much support? If so, forget it and chose something much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I know it is a such wide question but I need a guide which I can use sharepoint in small and medium hotel management such as room reservation and other function related to hotel .Please tell me which version can be used in this task .

Comment: SharePoint is an *application platform*. Almost any kind of business software can be built on top of SharePoint. Your question is way to broad, so you won't get any better answer as this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect that it could. However, I wouldn't recommend it unless it is the ONLY tool available and you have no budget for anything more suitable.

I would expect there to be many options for dedicated Hotel Management suites but SharePoint is a GENERAL tool for business information management and is difficult to bend into any specific shape.

If you absolutely *have* to use SP. I would start by looking at what information you need to capture and manage to help run the hotel. Prioritise the information so that you know where to begin first.

Then see if there are any elements that lend themselves to being managed in fairly simple lists. As a rule of thumb, if you are reaching for a spreadsheet to manage information lists then you can readily transfer that to one or more *custom lists* in SharePoint.

Be warned though that you will very quickly be wishing hard for a SharePoint developer and these don't come cheap.

Alternatively, a quick google for "[Hotel Management Suite](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=hotel%20management%20suite)" turned up a number of cloud-based systems specifically for doing that.

Either way, the first thing to do is to carefully document the **business requirements** needed to successfully run a hotel. Don't look for a technical solution first as that rarely works well. Know what you need first. That way you will be less likely to be led astray by "shiny things" or clever marketing.